# Sandbox not authenticating after creation

Tags: salesforcedx, sandbox, salesforcedx-cli

I'm trying to create a regular developer sandbox and waiting for it to self authenticate (as described in the salesforce documentation

> If the sandbox is created within the wait time, the CLI automatically authenticates in to the sandbox. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_create_clone_sandboxes.htm

but it errors out in the CLI after being created saying

```
Sandbox request testSbx(xxxxxxxxxxx) is Activating (95% completed). Sleeping 30 seconds. Will wait 21 minutes 30 seconds more before timing out.
ERROR running force:org:create:  Error authenticating with auth code due to: Value is undefined
```

Heres my command, all my parameters are correct

```
sfdx force:org:create -t sandbox sandboxName=testSbx licenseType=Developer -u fscProd -a testSbx -w 30
```

Comment: Using the most recent CLI?  Try `sfdx update` and then try the command again